# adding a method to android application

Tags: android

I am fairly new in android and Java and this question might seem a little bit a naive question , 
I am trying to write a method called getDispalay() , this will be a public with no retuen.
I will print a message saying I am in the getDisplay method .
In java it is very simple , It will be called in main method , But I do not know how i can use main method in activity class ? I mean how can I write a method and call it as I need it ?
Thanks

Comment: Look at a [hello world example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/)

Answer (score 3):

Go through this [**article**](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

As you said in java we call the function in main method .

In android if java class **extends**  **activity** you can call the method in  **Any of the life cycle event of activity** , It depends on your need . For example if you want to call method when you enter into activity follow this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)//To set up ui for activity

    getDispalay();
}

public void getDispalay(){
 //your actions
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you really need to do is [understand the activity lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html):

[image]

Once you have read through that then you will know how your Android app runs and what states and stages it transitions through.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the documentation about [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).
The `onCreate()` method would be comparable to `main()`.